# Is is possible to pass parameters between CC.NET projects?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I have CC.NET configured with 2 projects like this

`BuildApp`
`RunSmokeTests`

`RunSmokeTests` uses project trigger to start whenever `BuildApp` project finishes with `Success`.
When smoke tests fail I want to be able to send e-mails containing version number of our app (`${CCNetLabel}` from `BuildApp` project).

I can't find a way to do it. I thought this should be built in in CC.NET. I want to make sure that there is no such functionality in CC.NET before I come up with my own solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [remoteProjectLabeller](http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Remote_Project_Labeller) to label the SmokeTests project with the same label as the BuildApp project.

Otherwise you could use a [ForceBuildPublisher](http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/ForceBuildPublisher) in the publishers section of the BuildApp project,  where you can pass custom parameters.

If I were to suggest an option, I'd go for the latter as there is a underlying issue with the `remoteProjectTrigger` which can mean that your RunSmokeTests project can fire when BuildApp fails. It is also less efficient than the `ForceBuildPublisher`

For example

```
<forcebuild>
 <project>RunSmokeTests</project>
 <serverUri>tcp://buildserver:21234/CruiseManager.rem</serverUri>
 <integrationStatus>Success</integrationStatus>
 <!-- <enforcerName>BuildApp has finished </enforcerName> -->
 <parameters>
  <namedValue name="$BuildAppLabel" value="$Label" />
 </parameters>
</forcebuild>
```

There is a bug where but the `enforcerName` won't be passed,  so don't rely on that property.

In the RunSmokeTests project you should be able to read out the $BuildAppLabel for the email.

Comment: I found it 10 minutes after I posted this question :) This happens often. But still, thanks.